# How to grep standard error stream (stderr)?

Tags: grep, io-redirection, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to get the meta info of an audio clip. But I am unable to grep it.

```
    $ ffmpeg -i 01-Daemon.mp3  |grep -i Duration
    FFmpeg version SVN-r15261, Copyright (c) 2000-2008 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
      configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin 
      --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib
      --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=i386 --extra-cflags=-O2 
      ...
```

I checked, this ffmpeg output is directed to stderr.

```
$ ffmpeg -i 01-Daemon.mp3 2> /dev/null
```

So I think that grep is unable to read error stream to catch matching lines. How can we enable grep to read error stream?

Using [nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/) link, I redirected standard error stream to standard output stream, then grep worked.

```
$ ffmpeg -i 01-Daemon.mp3 2>&1 | grep -i Duration
  Duration: 01:15:12.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 64 kb/s
```

But what if we do not want to redirect stderr to stdout?

Comment: I believe that `grep` can only operate on stdout (Although I can't find the canonical source to back that up), which means that any stream needs to be converted to stdout first.

Comment: @Stefan: `grep` can only operate on stdin. It's the pipe created by the shell that connects grep's stdin to the other command's stdout. And the shell can only connect an stdout to an stdin.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. I think that's what I really meant to say , I just didn't think it through. Thanks @Giles.

Comment: Do you want it to still print stdout?

Comment: Here is the ZSH way: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265061/how-can-i-pipe-only-stderr-in-zsh

Comment: Did any of these answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 151):

If you're using `bash` why not employ anonymous pipes, in essence shorthand for what phunehehe said:

`ffmpeg -i 01-Daemon.mp3 2> >(grep -i Duration)`

Comment: +1 I used that to check `cp` output `cp -r dir* to 2> >(grep -v "svn")`

Comment: If you want the filtered redirected output on stderr again, add a `>&2`, e.g. `command 2> >(grep something >&2)`

Comment: Please explain how this works. `2>` redirects stderr to file, I get that. This reads from file `>(grep -i Duration)`. But the file is never stored? What is this technique called so I can read more about it?

Comment: It is "syntactic sugar" to create and a pipe (not file) and when complete remove that pipe.  They are effectively anonymous because they are not given a name in the filesystem.   Bash calls this process substitution.

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš Look up [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution). *"Process substitution can also be used to capture output that would normally go to a file, and redirect it to the input of a process."*

Comment: had to exclude stdout to grep just stderr 
your_output 1>/dev/null 2> >(ggrep -oP "(.*)(?=pattern)")

Comment: Also works in _zsh_, as seen in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265061/how-can-i-pipe-only-stderr-in-zsh

Comment: Do note that the target command of process substitution runs asynchronously. As a consequence stderr lines that get through the grep filter, may not appear at the place you would expect in the rest of the output, yes even on your next command prompt.

Answer (score 62):

None of the usual shells (even zsh) permit pipes with the `|` operator other than from stdout to stdin. But all Bourne-style shells support file descriptor reassignment (as in `1>&2`). So you can temporarily divert stdout to fd 3 and stderr to stdout, and later put fd 3 back onto stdout.
If `stuff` produces some output on stdout and some output on stderr, and you want to apply `filter` on the error output leaving the standard output untouched, you can use `{ stuff 2>&1 1>&3 | filter 1>&2; } 3>&1`.

```
$ stuff () {
  echo standard output
  echo more output
  echo standard error 1>&2
  echo more error 1>&2
}
$ filter () {
  grep a
}
$ { stuff 2>&1 1>&3 | filter 1>&2; } 3>&1
standard output
more output
standard error
```

---

Ksh, bash and zsh support pipes on arbitrary file descriptors, but they work differently: one command is the main command, and you can pipe its input or output into another command. [Process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) runs a command in the background with either its standard input or its standard output connected to a pipe which you can use in a redirection on the main command. Here you want to filter the standard error, so redirect it to an output process substitution.

```
$ stuff () {
  echo standard output
  echo more output
  echo standard error 1>&2
  echo more error 1>&2
}
$ filter () {
  grep a
}
$ stuff 2> >(filter)
standard output
more output
standard error
```

Note that there are two `>` characters with a space in between: that's `2>` to redirect standard output and `>(…)` to make a process substitution. The space is necessary because `2>>…` would be parsed as an append redirection.

Comment: This approach works. Unfortunately, in my case, if a non-zero return value is returned, it gets lost - the value returned is 0 for me. This may not always happen, but it happens in the case I'm currently looking at. Is there any way to save it?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Not sure what you're doing, but maybe `pipestatus` would help

Comment: @FaheemMitha, also `set -o pipefail` may be helpful here, depending on what you want to do with the error status.  (For instance if you have `set -e` turned on to fail on any errors, you probably want `set -o pipefail` also.)

Comment: @Wildcard Yes, I have `set -e` turned on to fail on any errors.

Comment: The `rc` shell allows piping stderr. See [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/how-to-grep-standard-error-stream-stderr/539053#539053) below.

Comment: @Rolf I've never encountered an rc script in the wild, I've never met anyone who uses it as an interactive shell, and I don't think I've ever seen a question about it on this site, so I feel safe in not including it in “usual shells”. Actually, that statement _is_ dodgy for another reason: process substitution isn't a shell pipeline, but it does use a pipe and it can pipe from stderr.

Comment: @Gilles Which statement is dodgy? My solution is based on piping, not process substitution.

Comment: In Zsh there's `|&` which pipes **both** stderr and stdout to another program.

Comment: Re: _None of the usual shells (even zsh) permits pipes other than from stdout to stdin._ What is the rationale?

Comment: @pmor Because no one's bothered to implement it, I suppose. And because there are similar constructs that together cover most scenarios: `|&` to pipe both stdout and stderr in zsh, process substitution in ksh/bash/zsh, file descriptor shuffling in any shell.

Comment: Slightly expanding this answer, in bash at least, maybe others too: `{ stuff [args] 2>&1 1>&3 | ts > stderr.log; } 3>&1 | ts > stdout.log` creates a pair of timestamped logfiles that keep stdout and stderr separate.  `ts` comes from the `moreutils` package, adds a timestamp in front of each line of its stdin, and puts that back on its stdout.  After all that, it still works to put a `&` on the very end, as usual, to fork it off to a parallel process.

Answer (score 32):

This is similar to phunehehe's "temp file trick", but uses a named pipe instead, allowing you to get results slightly closer to when they are output, which can be handy for long-running commands:

```
$ mkfifo mypipe
$ command 2> mypipe | grep "pattern" mypipe
```

In this construction, stderr will be directed to the pipe named "mypipe".   Since `grep` has been called with a file argument, it won't look to STDIN for its input.  Unfortunately, you will still have to clean up that named pipe once you are done.

If you are using Bash 4, there is a shortcut syntax for `command1 2>&1 | command2`, which is `command1 |& command2`.  However, I believe that this is purely a syntax shortcut, you are still redirecting STDERR to STDOUT.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871233/write-stdout-stderr-to-a-logfile-also-write-stderr-to-screen

Comment: That `|&` syntax is perfect to clean up bloated Ruby stderr stack traces. I can finally grep those without too much hassle.

Answer (score 29):

Gilles and Stefan Lasiewski's answers are both good, but this way is simpler:

```
ffmpeg -i 01-Daemon.mp3 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep "pattern"
```

I am assuming you don't want `ffmpeg's` stdout printed.

How it works:

- pipes first

  - ffmpeg and grep are started, with ffmpeg's stdout going to grep's stdin
- redirections next, left to right

  - ffmpeg's stderr is set to whatever its stdout is (currently the pipe)
  - ffmpeg's stdout is set to /dev/null

Comment: This description is confusing to me. The last two bullets make me think "redirect stderr to stdout", then "redirect stdout (with stderr, now) to /dev/null". However, this isn't what this is really doing. Those statements seem to be reversed.

Comment: @Steve There's no "with stderr" in the second bullet.  Have you seen http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37660/order-of-redirections ?

Comment: No, I mean that's *my* interpretation of how you described it in English. The link you provided is very useful, though.

Comment: Why was it needed to be redirected to /dev/null ?

Comment: @KanwaljeetSingh So `stdout` goes away leaving us with only `stderr`, otherwise `grep` will operate on the mixed stream of `stdout` and `stderr` produced by `ffmpeg`

Comment: Here is the ZSH way: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265061/how-can-i-pipe-only-stderr-in-zsh

Comment: By the way this is the _best_ solution since it's shell-independent.

Answer (score 13):

See below for the script used in these tests.

Grep can only operate on stdin, so therefore you must convert the stderr stream in a form that Grep can parse.

Normally, stdout and stderr are both printed to your screen:

```
$ ./stdout-stderr.sh
./stdout-stderr.sh: Printing to stdout
./stdout-stderr.sh: Printing to stderr
```

To hide stdout, but still print stderr do this:

```
$ ./stdout-stderr.sh >/dev/null
./stdout-stderr.sh: Printing to stderr
```

But grep won't operate on stderr! You would expect the following command to suppress lines which contain 'err', but it does not.

```
$ ./stdout-stderr.sh >/dev/null |grep --invert-match err
./stdout-stderr.sh: Printing to stderr
```

Here's the solution.

The following Bash syntax will hide output to stdout, but will still show stderr. First we pipe stdout to /dev/null, then we convert stderr to stdout, because Unix pipes will only operate on stdout.  You can still grep the text.

```
$ ./stdout-stderr.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep err
./stdout-stderr.sh: Printing to stderr
```

(Note that the above command is *different* then `./command >/dev/null 2>&1`, which is a very common command).

Here's the script used for testing. This prints one line to stdout and one line to stderr:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Print a message to stdout
echo "$0: Printing to stdout"
# Print a message to stderr
echo "$0: Printing to stderr" >&2

exit 0
```

Comment: If you switch the redirections around, you don't need all the braces.  Just do `./stdout-stderr.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep err`.

Comment: You say it's different, but not in what way: `./command >/dev/null 2>&1` How does that differ from `./command 2>&1 >/dev/null`?

Answer (score 9):

`bash` can redirect stdout to stdin stream via regular pipe - `|`
It also can redirect both stdout and stderr to stdin by `|&`

Comment: This method is useful for when you want to exclude certain error messages but see the rest, such as `asdf |& grep -v error_message_to_ignore`

Answer (score 6):

When you pipe the output of one command to another (using `|`), you are only redirecting standard output. So that should explain why

```
ffmpeg -i 01-Daemon.mp3 | grep -i Duration
```

doesn't output what you wanted (it does work, though).

If you don't want to redirect error output to standard output you can redirect error output to a file, then grep it later

```
ffmpeg -i 01-Daemon.mp3 2> /tmp/ffmpeg-error
grep -i Duration /tmp/ffmpeg-error
```

Comment: Thanks. `it does work, though`, you mean it is working on your machine? Secondly, as you pointed out using pipe we can only redirect stdout. I am interested in some command or bash feature that will let me redirect stderr. (but not the temp file trick)

Comment: @Andrew I mean, the command works the way it has been designed to work. It just doesn't work the way you want it to :)

Comment: I don't know of any way that can redirect error output of a command to standard input of another. Would be interesting if someone can point that out.

Answer (score 6):

You may swap the streams.  This would enable you to `grep` the original standard error stream while still getting the output that originally went to standard output in the terminal:

```
somecommand 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3- | grep 'pattern'
```

This works by first creating a new file descriptor (3) open for output and setting it to the standard error stream (`3>&2`). Then we redirect standard error to standard output (`2>&1`). Finally standard output is redirected to the original standard error, and the new file descriptor is closed (`1>&3-`).

In your case:

```
ffmpeg -i 01-Daemon.mp3 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3- | grep -i Duration
```

Testing it:

```
$ ( echo "error" >&2; echo "output" ) 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3- | grep "error"
output
error

$ ( echo "error" >&2; echo "output" ) 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3- | grep -v "error"
output
```

Comment: Convoluted as a solution but great for demonstrating how redirection operators work! Also to show how to swap FDs.

Comment: This is not perfect, as all the resulting text is being output to STDOUT.

Comment: @Trolzen The question did not specify what to do with the original standard output stream.  If you want to discard it, redirect it to `/dev/null` rather than hooking it up to the standard error stream.  My answer is built around the idea that one may still want to see the standard output; hence, I suggest swapping the streams.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, you're right, the question didn't specify that. Hence I said "not perfect", but not "wrong". And I'm talking not about discarding the initial output or not, I'm talking about keeping original STDOUT and STDERR separate. And there's a [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3540) for that.

Comment: @Trolzen In that case, I'm not entirely sure what it is that you want to say.  I mean, it's nice of you to make me aware of that other answer.  If that is a better answer for what you are doing, then, by all means, use that answer instead.

Comment: @Kusalananda Actually, I'm not quite right. Your solution dos not _merge_ resulting stdout and stderr, but swaps them. And my comments are mostly addressed not to you, but to future readers, who will be choosing an appropriate solution in their cases.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use the `rc` shell in this case.

First install the package (it's less than 1MB).

This is an example of how you would discard `stdout` and pipe `stderr` to grep in `rc`:

`find /proc/ >[1] /dev/null |[2] grep task`

You can do it without leaving Bash:

`rc -c 'find /proc/ >[1] /dev/null |[2] grep task'`

As you may have noticed, the syntax is straightforward, which makes this my preferred solution.

You can specify which file descriptor you want piped inside brackets, just after the pipe character.

Standard file descriptors are numbered as such:

- 0 : Standard input
- 1 : Standard ouptut
- 2 : Standard error

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the bash subprocess example:

echo two lines to stderr and tee stderr to a file, grep the tee and pipe back out to stdout

```
(>&2 echo -e 'asdf\nfff\n') 2> >(tee some.load.errors | grep 'fff' >&1)
```

stdout:

```
fff
```

some.load.errors (eg stderr):

```
asdf
fff
```

Answer (score -1):

try this command

- create file with random name
- send output to the file
- send content of the file to pipe
- grep

ceva --> just a variable name (english = something)

```
ceva=$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM; ffmpeg -i qwerty_112_0_0_record.flv 2>$ceva; cat $ceva | grep Duration; rm $ceva;
```

Comment: I would use `/tmp/$ceva`, better than littering the current directory with temporary files - and you are assuming that the current directory is writable.

Comment: If you are going to create a temp file use `mktemp`.