# How does file descriptor re-assigment work?

Tags: bash, file-descriptors

In a way this question is a extension of [another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3514) question.

In bash you can do pretty neat stuff with file descriptors. Like

```
{ command > /dev/null } 2>&1 | grep filter;
```

to grep on **stderr** only.

My Question[s]:

- How many levels of descriptors are there. ( How high can the "numbers" go) ?
- Appart from `1` and `2` ( which are **stdout** and **stderr** ), what is the meaning and general use of those other "numbers"?
- Is the order in which they are specified important?
  e.g. `command 1>&2 3>&1 2>&3` versus  `command  2>&3 3>&1  1>&2`

Comment: You probably knew this already, but `1` is **stdout**; `0` is **stdin**.

Comment: the `0` **stdin** is news to me :) I learnt something +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You may well expect them to go up to `63` on a typical Linux box.
- There is (was?) `stdlog`, but it's rarely used (I believe I never saw one).
- The order is important: check `man bash` REDIRECTION.

Comment: I don't think there's anything standard about 3 going to syslog, it just happens to be the first opened by many programs that already have the standard 0, 1, 2 open.

Comment: @Gilles: actually I was talking about `stdlog`, not `syslog`.  Too bad, it's not easy to find something viable about that.  I believe it was obsoleted long ago.  And I must be wrong for putting `3` as it's default number... :-P

Comment: From light googling, `stdlog` might have been a FORTRAN thing that never made it into Unix. I didn't find anything like a reference for this, though.

Comment: yeah, that seems pretty much like one of those false memories...

Answer (score 1):

The number you need is given by the maximum file descriptor count from the [ulimit(1)](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?ulimit+2) command.