# How to prefix any output in a bash script?

Tags: bash

When a script runs, commands in it may output some text to stdout/stderr. Bash itself may also output some text.

But if a few scripts are running at the same time, it is hard to identify where does an error come from.

So is it possible to insert a prefix to all output of the script? Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
prefix 'PREFIX' &2
echo "wrong!" >&2
```

Then:

```
$ ./script.sh
PREFIXwrong!
```

Comment: How are you running multiple scripts at once?

Comment: Could something like `function echo() { /bin/echo $PREFIX$*; }` help you?

Comment: @Jesse_b by a parent script or something. The scripts are not depending on each other. So running in parallel saves some time.

Comment: @Philippos But this does not affect the command called in the script. Also, for example, `[ x -eq 1 ]` caused shell itself reporting error, which this kind of way could not help.

Comment: There is an example with timestamp too: https://gist.github.com/reduardo7/5d8443130495d3ad0e630eb344a37707

Comment: @EduardoCuomo Thanks.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can redirect stderr/stdout to a process substitution that adds the prefix of choice. For example, this script:

```
#! /bin/bash
exec > >(trap "" INT TERM; sed 's/^/foo: /')
exec 2> >(trap "" INT TERM; sed 's/^/foo: (stderr) /' >&2)
echo foo
echo bar >&2
date
```

Produces this output:

```
foo: foo
foo: (stderr) bar
foo: Fri Apr 27 20:04:34 IST 2018
```

The first two lines redirect stdout and stderr respectively to sed commands that add `foo:`  and `foo: (stderr)` to the input.
The calls to the shell built-in command `trap` make sure that the subshell does not exit when terminating the script with `Ctrl+C` or by sending the `SIGTERM` signal using `kill $pid`. This ensures that your shell won't forcefully terminate your script because the `stdout` file descriptor disappears when `sed` exits because it received the termination signal as well. Effectively you can still use exit traps in your main script and `sed` will still be running to process any output generated while running your exit traps. The subshell should still exit after your main script ends so `sed` process won't be left running forever.

Comment: Note that doing this one loses the guarantee that ordering will be consistent between the two streams -- if you write, say, five lines to stdout, one line to stderr, and five more lines to stdout, it's *not at all* guaranteed that the line written to stderr will have five stdout lines before it and five after it when it finally gets flushed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Do you have any extra information on that ? A couple links perhaps ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I think the dupe candidate suggested by you and the possible dupe for that question are good for that - both have some discussion on retaining ordering of the output.

Comment: If the job is only add a prefix, I'd save on `sed` call with something like `while read -r; do echo "$PREFIX$REPLY"; done`

Comment: @jno depends on the prefix. Something like `ts` could be used for nicely timestamped output.

Comment: @muru, who keeps you from usung,  say,  `$(date)` instead of mere `$PREFIX`?

Comment: @jno the thought of running a `date` for each line instead of having a long-running `ts` which processes all lines.

Comment: @muru, the use of `ts` (as well as, say, `cat -n` to number lines) is the same as `sed` — just another filter. I meant the original question for arbitrary prefix insertion. The exact choice obviously depends on what one want to insert (static text, "serializers" like line numbers and stamps, or something even more "dynamic") and expected output rate.

Comment: @jno well, yes, that's why I gave an example of process substitution that readers can adapt to run whatever command they want, instead of worrying about premature optimization on `sed` calls.

Answer (score 13):

You could pipe the output through some way of replacing lines:

```
some long running stuff | sed -e 's/^/Some said: /;'
```

Also check [24337](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24337/piping-stderr-vs-stdout)

Or just direct separate outputs to separate files/screen(1) tabs/tabs in your terminal/...

Comment: This does not help with stderr. And my requirement is more like running in console at boot up, instead of terminal window.

Comment: But now I cannot get the value of `$?`...

Answer (score 7):

One option in bash is to do this by redirecting to process substitutions, something like this:

```
./script.sh > >(sed 's/^/script: /') 2> >(sed 's/^/script (err): /' >&2)
```

This has the problem that output may be out of order (as Charles Duffy mentioned in a comment). It's also really annoyingly unweildy. But you could make a wrapper function for it:

```
prefixwith() {
    local prefix="$1"
    shift
    "$@" > >(sed "s/^/$prefix: /") 2> >(sed "s/^/$prefix (err): /" >&2)
}
prefixwith "From script" ./script.sh
```

Or make it even simpler by having it use the command name as a prefix:

```
prefixoutput() {
    local prefix="From ${1##*/}"
    "$@" > >(sed "s/^/$prefix: /") 2> >(sed "s/^/$prefix (err): /" >&2)
}
prefixoutput ./script.sh
```