# grep does not colorize properly

Tags: grep, regular-expression, strace

I am trying to pipe a output from command to grep.

```
$ strace a.out | grep --color=always "mmap"
```

but it only outputs non-colorized output of strace:

```
...
mmap(NULL, 503808, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa42389d000
write(1, "got memory: (address=0x7fa42389d"..., 37got memory: (address=0x7fa42389d010)
) = 37
mmap(NULL, 503808, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa423822000
write(1, "got memory: (address=0x7fa423822"..., 37got memory: (address=0x7fa423822010)
) = 37
mmap(NULL, 503808, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa4237a7000
write(1, "got memory: (address=0x7fa4237a7"..., 37got memory: (address=0x7fa4237a7010)
) = 37
mmap(NULL, 503808, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa42372c000
write(1, "got memory: (address=0x7fa42372c"..., 37got memory: (address=0x7fa42372c010)
) = 37
```

Here it is not colorized, but should. How to achieve it?

Comment: does `echo 'foo mmap 123' | grep --color=always 'mmap'` give you colored output? If so, `strace` output is probably on `stderr` and you are seeing entire output instead of just the lines with `mmap`

Comment: @Sundeep you right, I forgot, the strace gives a output to stderr, I thing there is a option in strace to redicrect its output, which could solve it

Comment: @Sundeep I have tried this: `strace a.out -o >(grep --color=always brk)`, but still no color

Comment: try `strace a.out  2>&1 | grep` or `strace a.out |& grep`

Answer (score 1):

Since `strace` output is on the standard error stream, use

```bash
strace a.out 2>&1 | grep --color=always -- 'mmap';
```

or, if you're using `bash`,

```bash
strace a.out |& grep --color=always -- 'mmap';
```

In case all the available output is required:

```bash
strace a.out |& grep --color=always -E -- 'mmap|';
```

---

See also [Piping STDERR vs. STDOUT](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24337/piping-stderr-vs-stdout) for more details.