# Where to place a Bash shell redirection for a command?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, file-descriptors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Order of redirections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37660/order-of-redirections)

Apart from the standalone `exec >&2` to redirect the current shell's input and output are there any behavioral differences in the following commands:

1. `echo -en "C\nB\nA\n" | sort 2>/dev/stdout >&2`
2. `echo -en "C\nB\nA\n" 2>/dev/stdout >&2 | sort`
3. `2>/dev/stdout >&2 echo -en "C\nB\nA\n" | sort`

If the above commands were equivalent which is the preferred variant?

Comment: None of those is idiomatic.  They all contain redundancies.  How did you come up with those?  Are they homework?

Comment: I find your comment quite harsh. The above commands purely serve as illustrative examples. I'm also very well aware that the net effect of `2>/dev/stdout >&2` is zero. The question is primarily concerned with "where to place" and only secondarily with "what does" the redirection.

Comment: @TimFriske The net effect of `2>/dev/stdout >&2` is most definitely *not* zero.

Comment: @ChrisDown I meant that the output sent to `>` is still `/dev/stdout` after `2>/dev/stdout >&2`. The redirection itself definetly has its side effects.

Comment: "Where to place" depends on what you want it to do.  And I can't figure that out from your question.  You seem to fundamentally misunderstand `>&2`.  Please read the man page first, then ask a clear question.

Comment: @Mikel No, that earlier question deals with switching the `>&2` and the `2>foo` but not with the placement of the redirection within a simple command or a pipeline.

Comment: Right.  There's at least two, if not three issues this question touches on, without ever clearly identifying what the actual question is.  The linked question helps understand that `2>/dev/stdout >&2` contains redundancies.  The question needs to have these redundancies removed, and then be recast in the form of a clear question.  If it was only about redirections in pipelines, it would indeed be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, in a *simple command* (basically, the name of a program followed by some arguments), the relative position of arguments and redirections doesn't matter. You can even have redirections before the command name. The following are all equivalent:

```
foo --bar qux >out 2>err
foo >out --bar 2>err
>out 2>err foo --bar qux
```

(I won't list all the possibilities.) It's usual to put the redirections at the end, so you might surprise a future reader if you don't do that. However, it's only a matter of style. There is some benefit to putting input redirections before the command and output redirections afterward, particularly in pipelines, because it keeps the reading order identical to the processing order:

```
<input.txt command1 | command2 | command3 >output.txt
```

(contrast `command1 <input.txt | command2 …`, which puts the origin after the first processing step.)

In compound commands, you do need to put the redirections at the end; for example, in the following snippets, you can't put the redirection anywhere else:

```
while some_predicate; do some_action; done <in >out
{ command1; command2; } <in >out
```

When there are multiple redirections, the order is important if they overlap, i.e. if they have file descriptors in common. See [Order of redirections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37660/order-of-redirections)

In a pipeline, redirections apply to each piped command. In your examples, the redirections apply to (1) the `sort` command only, (2,3) the `echo` command only. As explained above, (2) and (3) are equivalent.

In (2) and (3), the output from `echo` ends up at the same place it was before the redirection. If you'd written `echo -en "C\nB\nA\n" >&2 | sort`, there would be no output to stdout from the command on the left-hand side of the pipe, so `sort` would see an empty stdin.

You can redirect the input or output of a block of commands by putting them in braces:

```
{ command1 | command2; } 2>error.log
```

I assume your choice of redirections was for demonstration purposes only — `2>/dev/stdout >&2` is a complex way of writing `2>&1` (redirect standard error (i.e. fd 2) to wherever standard output (i.e. fd 1) currently goes).

Comment: Indeed the `2>/dev/stdout >&2` redirections served for the purpose of demonstration.

Comment: On Linux `2>/dev/stdout >&2` is not equivalent to `2>&1` as it reopens the file which will reset file pointers to the start of the file.

Answer (score 2):

1 is different than 2 and 3. 2 and 3 are identical.

In version 1, `C\nB\nA\n` is sent to `sort`. `sort`'s FD 2 is mapped from its original destination (`STDERR`) to `STDOUT` and then FD 1, which would have gone to `STDOUT` anyway, is sent to... `sort`'s `STDOUT` again (rather pointlessly).

In versions 2 and 3, `echo`'s FD 2 is mapped from its original destination (`STDERR`) to `STDOUT` and then FD 1, which would have gone to `STDOUT` anyway, is sent to `echo`'s `STDOUT`.

Functionally these commands will only produce different output if one of the commands sends something to `STDERR`.

In version 1, if `echo` outputs something to FD 2, it will go to `STDERR`, but in 2 and 3, it will go to `STDOUT` (and thus also be piped to `sort`). Also, in version 1, if `sort` sends something to FD 2, it will go to `STDOUT`, whereas in versions 2 and 3, that output will go to `STDERR`.

In terms of the "preferred variant", you should really be using something more like this (assuming you want `echo`'s `STDERR` to go to `sort`):

```
echo -en "C\nB\nA\n" 2>&1 | sort
```

This works because FD 1 already goes to `STDOUT` by default, just have FD 2 copy the file description to its descriptor.