# How do you remember the syntax for 2>&1 redirection

Tags: io-redirection

Do you have a mnemonic or system? This has bothered me for years I always have to look it up

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are a C programmer, you can think of `&1` as "the address of 1" so `2>&1` reads "redirect file descriptor #2 to the same place as #1".

Comment: Don't know if it helps... Mnemonics are quite a personal stuff.

Comment: +12 That's also a correct description of what's happening.

Comment: I wonder if it's how it was thought of ("the address of 1")  when it was invented. As some people contributed heavily to both the C language and UNIX when they were invented, it's possible

Comment: I might start using this one instead ;)

Answer (score 3):

**"Two to and one"** ("to" being `>`) makes more logical sense to me than "Two and to one", which is what I might usually confuse it with.  If you consider "and one" as a single noun (a place), it also makes grammatical sense in context, which is harder to do with "Two and to one" -- you'd have to consider "to one" a single noun, and it still would not make contextual sense.

Comment: I don't understand

Answer (score 2):

When you write `2>&1`, you're saying "standard error goes to standard output".

Let's break that down.

First you want to memorize that standard error is `2` and standard output is `1`.

So you've got `2` something something `1`.

"goes to" is written `>`.

So you've got `2>` something `1`.

`2>filename` means send standard error to `filename`.  But you don't want to send it to a file called `1`.  You want something else: the number of a file that's already open.  That's what the `&` is for.

So `2>&1`.

You can also think of it like you were doing an assignment, where the `>` is like an equals and the `&` is like a `$`, compare:

```
f=$1
2>&1
```

To understand a command line with multiple redirections, the important thing to know is that the redirections are done left to right.  See [Order of redirections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37660/order-of-redirections) for more details about that.

Answer (score 2):

Not a mnemonic, but I read it as follows:

`0` is stdin.
`1` is stdout. 
`2` is stderr.
`>` is into.
`<` is out of.
`&` is file descriptor (in some shells).

```
2>&1
2      >    &               1
stderr into file descriptor 1

redirect stderr into stdout
```

It might change if you have messed with any of the file descriptors prior to the redirection...

```
2>somefile 1>&2
2      >    somefile     1      >    &2
stderr into somefile and stdout into file descriptor 2

redirect stderr into somefile and stdout into somefile.
```

Answer (score 0):

I remembered that it is always 2 -> 1. Stderr to stdout.

The middle part is always the hard one and I always messed it up, until I remembered that first comes the sharp character `>`, then the character I can't write in real life `&`.

So never `2&>1`, always `2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

If you understand that FD2 is STDERR, you might think, "Oh, and capture STDERR where ever I send STDOUT (FD1)".

Answer (score 0):

My coworkers and I usually say "two is greater than one", because most of us don't always remember that `stderr` is file descriptor `2` and `stdout` is `1` (especially those new to unix/linux), so the other mnemonics about redirecting `stderr` don't really work.  Only problem is, you still have to remember where the ampersand goes!