# rsync send all output to /dev/null

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, io-redirection

I have the following bash command

```
rsync -q host:/usr/files/client.txt /home/myuser/ 2>&1>/dev/null
```

But it's still giving me

```
Unexpected local arg: /home/myuser/
If arg is a remote file/dir, prefix it with a colon (:).
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1228) [Receiver=3.0.9]
```

And I'm not sure how to proceed and avoid any output.

How do I silence all the output if the following doesn't work?

Comment: [Order of redirections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37660/order-of-redirections) (however IMHO it would be better to fix the errors rather than silence them)

Comment: @steeldriver there's no errors besides this one just some unnecessary messages