# How does redirection to pv actually work?

Tags: shell-script, pipe, io-redirection, pv

I am trying to understand how the redirection is exactly working in [this command](https://www.tecmint.com/monitor-copy-backup-tar-progress-in-linux-using-pv-command/)

```
# tar -czf - ./Downloads/ | (pv -p --timer --rate --bytes > backup.tgz)
```

What is the english translation ?

All the data of `tar` is redirected as input to `pv` and then `pv` redirects it to `backup.tgz` ?

**Then why is the bracket around `pv` required ?**

Then how does this redirection make sense ?

```
tar -czf - ./Documents/ | (pv -n > backup.tgz) 2>&1 | dialog --gauge "Progress" 10 70
```

After `pv` what is the meaning of `2>&1` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/86440) and [Order of redirections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37660/86440) for background.

```
tar -czf - ./Downloads/ | (pv -p --timer --rate --bytes > backup.tgz)
```

tells the shell to run `tar -czf - ./Downloads/` with standard output redirected to `(pv -p --timer --rate --bytes > backup.tgz)`.

```
(pv -p --timer --rate --bytes > backup.tgz)
```

tells the shell to run `pv -p --timer --rate --bytes` with standard input connected to the pipe from `tar`, and standard output redirected to `backup.tgz`. The overall effect, since `tar` is told to create a compressed archive, outputting to its standard output (`f -`), is to build a compressed archive, pipe it through `pv`, and then have `pv` write it to `backup.tgz`. `pv` displays a progress bar, updated as data flows through it.

The parentheses aren’t required.

You second command changes the second half of the first pipe:

```
(pv -n > backup.tgz) 2>&1
```

again writes to `backup.tgz`, but also redirects the subshell’s (introduced by the parentheses) standard error to standard output, and feeds *that* into `dialog` which produces its own progress display.

The parentheses are required here if the redirections are set up in the order given in your command: `pv -n > backup.tgz 2>&1` would redirect both `pv`’s standard output and standard error to `backup.tgz`, which isn’t what you want. The desired effect can also be achieved by redirecting standard error first: `pv -n 2>&1 > backup.tgz`.