# iptables spams console even when output is redirected

Tags: iptables

How do you get the thing to be quieter?

In my firewall `sh` script, I want to test whether or not a chain already exists -- to either create it or flush it.

```
# iptables -L THISISNOTACHAIN 2>&1 >/dev/null; echo $?
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
#
```

Comment: Try `>/dev/null 2>&1`  - see [Order of redirections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37660/order-of-redirections)

Comment: That is the solution!