# CRON 2>&1 >/dev/null vs >/dev/null 2>&1

Tags: linux, shell, cron, io-redirection

I just created a tiny shell script to be run every minute.

What happened was that it started flooding my `mail`.

```
$ crontab -l
* * * * * /home/user/bin/test 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

---

I changed the redirection to `>/dev/null 2>&1`, and it stopped.

I thought `2>&1 >/dev/null` and  `>/dev/null 2>&1` are equal in shell at least... Now I hesitate, are they (equal) and it's just the CRON programmed this way?

Comment: See [Order of redirections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37660/order-of-redirections) (although be aware that cronjobs are more likely to be run in /bin/sh than bash).

Answer (score 1):

Those two commands are not the same.

`1>stdout filename` must be located in between the `command` and `2>&1`

---

```
$ command  1>  stdoutput_filename  2>&1
```

`2>` => redirect stderr, `&1` => means `stdoutput_filename`.

```
$ command 2>&1 > /dev/null => &1 does not mean /dev/null
```

### Example

```
$ ls issue issue.net nofile 2>&1 > /tmp/testfile
```

> ```
> ls: cannot access nofile: No such file or directory
> ```

```
$ cat /tmp/testfile
issue
issue.net
```

```
$ ls issue issue.net nofile 1> /tmp/testfile 2>&1
```

```
$ cat /tmp/testfile
ls: cannot access nofile: No such file or directory
issue
issue.net
```

Comment: It doesn't have to between the two, it just has to before `2>&1`. It can be before the command.