# Ambiguous bash stream redirection

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stdout, stderr

I am trying to understand the Bash redirections ([3.6. Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)).
I prepared the test envronment and I'm trying to understand the order of operations with redirections and order of created file descriptors.

Test env preparation:

```bash
cd `mktemp -d`
mkdir no_access_dir
chmod 000 no_access_dir
```

`ls -R` outpus is the following:

```
.:
no_access_dir
ls: cannot open directory './no_access_dir': Permission denied
```

First 2 stdout lines followed by 1 stderr output.

I checked the behavior of commands using the `3.6.2 Redirecting Output`, `3.6.4 Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error`, `3.6.8 Duplicating File Desciptors` and `3.6.9 Moving File Desciptors`

Here are the test commands :

```bash
ls -R 2>&1 > a    # 1. 3.6.2 or 3.6.8
ls -R 2>&1- > a   # 2. 3.6.9
ls -R 1>&2 > a    # 3. 3.6.2 or 3.6.8
ls -R 1>&2- > a   # 4. 3.6.9
ls -R > a 2>&1    # 5. 3.6.4
ls -R > a 1>&2    # 6. 3.6.4
```

Output descriptions:

1. `ls -R 2>&1 > a` - File a contains itself and doesn't contain the error msg - WHY?
2. `ls -R 2>&1- > a` - nothing changes from the situation above - SO WHAT'S THE POINT IN MOVING FD
3. `ls -R 1>&2 > a` - still nothing changes
4. `ls -R 1>&2- > a` - no error msg displayed and error msg still not visible in the file
5. `ls -R > a 2>&1` - both streams are redirected to file - works as expected
6. `ls -R > a 1>&2` - File a is empty because stdout is redirected to stdout

I understand the output in `5` and `6`, however why in commands `1`, `2`, `3` the output is the same - and why number `4` doesn't display the error message nor this message is saved in a file - it's a mystery.

So my questions are:

1. What is the difference between redirecting output `[n]>word` and duplicating fd `[n]>&digit` and which one is used the I do `2>&1`
2. Why in case `1` and `2` the output file doesn't contain the error message - the stderr stream has been redirected to the stdout
3. What's the use case of Moving FD?
4. Where is the error message from `4`? It's not in the output file and it's not in the console.

My current understanding is:
`ls -R > a 2>&1` - first Bash creates file `a` then runs a command `ls -R` which finds the newly created file `a` and displays the `stderr` msg which is redirected to `stdout` and saved to file - but the syntax in this case is very ambiguous

Comment: Me think it is best explanation https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176214/153329

Answer (score 0):

The issue is kind of in the timing - the position on the command line matters, since the redirections are applied in sequence as they are encountered. So for points 1-4, it doesn't matter that there is a `> a` coming afterwards - that will only be applied  when it is eventually reached. Everything done to `&2` happens before the `> a`, so redirecting to `&1` at that point will still refer to what it was before, i.e. your terminal output