# How to extract certain data from an MQTT stream

Tags: text-processing, streaming, data

I type `mosquitto_sub -d -t +/#` from the Ubuntu terminal to access the MQTT stream.

However I would like to see only a specific set of data from the MQTT stream. I've added `| grep -v PING` so everything still be printed except for lines with PING in them but that didn't work.

I've tried `| grep -A1 PUBLISH` so I can see lines from the MQTT with PUBLISH in them, nothing changed: I just get the whole MQTT stream nothing gets filtered out.

How can I see the certain thing that I want to see from an MQTT stream? Alternatively; how can I filter certain things out of the MQTT stream or how can I extract data from the MQTT stream?

My input from the ubuntu terminal is as follows `$ mosquitto_sub -d -t +/#` and I've tried `$ mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# | grep -v PING` and `$ mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# | grep -A1 PUBLISH` but it just streams everything, doesn't grep anything. The output is as follows:

```
ed@agharta:~$ mosquitto_sub -d -t +/#
Received CONNACK
Received SUBACK
Subscribed (mid: 1): 0
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/jsyd/TEST/001/d/status', ... (34 bytes))
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/jsyd/TEST/001/d/SVlts', ... (28 bytes))
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
```

For example how can I *only* see the PUBLISH from the live stream and not the PINGs?

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample input and output...

Comment: @jasonwryan I've included the input and output from the terminal

Comment: `sed -n '/Subscribed/p' stream`

Comment: @jasonwryan I looked up http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-15 and the format is `sed -n '/PATTERN/p' file`; I'm not too sure how to filter out specific words like "PING" and what the `/PATTERN/` and `file` refer to; Simply put I just don't get it from reading it.

Comment: Well, it is unclear what you want to filter on: I took from your question you only wanted lines with the word "Subscribe" in them...

Comment: @jasonwryan I just want words with 'PUBLISH' in them so I am guessing it would be `sed -n '/PUBLISH/p' stream` however what does the `stream` component do?

Comment: This is why I asked for sample input and output... Editing in the crucial information afterwards is not that helpful.

Comment: @jasonwryan this is a live feed that I am accessing, there was no data when I posted it. However in the code `sed -n '/PUBLISH/p' stream` what does the `stream` component do?

Comment: @3kstc - Your commands are OK but note that `grep` doesn't operate on `stderr`. [Apparently](https://answers.launchpad.net/mosquitto/+question/252384) `mosquitto_sub` logs to `stderr` so (with `bash`) you could try something like `mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2> >(grep PUBLISH)`. For more details & options read the answers [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3514).

Comment: @don_crissti it works like a treat, but looking at the forum provided  I didn't understand what the 2> does and also `[what does this value mean]>[what does this space do?]>(grep [grepped keyword])` Additionally if I wanted to grep two or more keywords, how would I do it?

Comment: @3kstc - redirection and process substitution... [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/) is some stuff for you to read; as to _grep more patterns_, [here's](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/grep-or-and-not-operators/) some more to read :) HTH.

Comment: @don_crissti it's my second week in with bash and linux, - massive learning curve, I've [looked at dot point 22](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/) I think I understand, but I've one [last question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186718/how-can-i-remove-a-carriage-return-add-a-time-stamp-and-ignore-some-data-from-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in the process of writing the following answer to the other, related question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/187109/52934) when it was deleted. I don't know if you'll be able to follow that link, but *(an abbreviation of)* the example data referred to below is this:

```
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/gf/TMX6BP/075/d/SVlts', ... (28 bytes))
86,1224830,27610 27869 17565
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/gf/TMX6BP/075/d/status', ... (39 bytes))
86,1243000,164573,-33.836465,151.051189
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
```

So I wrote the following to make it work with `sed` like this:

```
mosquitto ... 2>&1 | 
sed -u "/.*PUBLISH[^']*\([^,]*,\).*/!d 
       s//\1/;N;s/[\%]/&&/g;s/'/&\\\\&&/g
       s/.*/printf '&'/;s/\n/'&date '+[%s,]/"|  
sh -s
```

Now, I don't have your `mosquitto` program, but if I copy your whole example thing to my clipboard, and do:

```
xsel -bo | sed ... | sh ...
```

It prints:

```
'm/gf/TMX6BP/075/d/SVlts',[1425002404,]86,1224830,27610 27869 17565
'm/gf/TMX6BP/075/d/status',[1425002404,]86,1243000,164573,-33.836465,151.051189
'm/NWRL/TMX/098/d/SVlts',[1425002404,]806,3040421,7549 7750 3904
'm/NWRL/TMX/098/d/status',[1425002404,]806,3069000,59666,-33.836465,151.051189
'm/NWRL/TMX/098/d/SVlts',[1425002404,]810,5440995,6143 7807 4076
'm/NWRL/TMX/098/d/status',[1425002404,]810,5489000,59897,-33.836465,151.051189
```

...which is, I think, what you want. It works by ensuring all of the input is safely quoted for both the shell and for `date` and `printf`'s format strings, and then constructing shell commands out of each line pair.

For each line pair `printf` first prints the contents of the first line w/out a trailing `\n`ewline, then `date` prints the `[timestamp]` in seconds since the epoch followed by the contents of the second line and a trailing `\n`ewline. `sed`'s output looks something like this:

```
printf ''\''m/gf/TMX6BP/075/d/SVlts'\'','
date '+[%s,]86,1224830,27610 27869 17565'
```

None of the commands printed at `sh`, of course, are executed until `sed` prints them at it. So if `sed` were reading `mosquitto`'s output and one line came in later than a previous one then the `date` line would reflect that.

For example:

```
(set -f; IFS='
';  for l in $(xsel -bo)
    do  printf %s\\n "$l"
        sleep 1
    done) |
sed -u "/.*PUBLISH[^']*\([^,]*,\).*/!d 
       s//\1/;N;s/[\%]/&&/g;s/'/&\\\\&&/g
       s/.*/printf '&'/;s/\n/'&date '+[%s,]/"|  
sh -s
```

...which waits a second before printing every output line at `sed` in order to more faithfully emulate a live stream. It takes advantage of the GNU `sed` `-u`nbuffered switch to get `sed`'s output flushed as often as possible, but if that is not available to you let me know and I will show you how to block out a pipe correctly w/ `dd` to avoid buffering issues.

Anyway, the above prints:

```
'm/gf/TMX6BP/075/d/SVlts',[1425002863,]86,1224830,27610 27869 17565
'm/gf/TMX6BP/075/d/status',[1425002865,]86,1243000,164573,-33.836465,151.051189
'm/NWRL/TMX/098/d/SVlts',[1425002869,]806,3040421,7549 7750 3904
'm/NWRL/TMX/098/d/status',[1425002871,]806,3069000,59666,-33.836465,151.051189
'm/NWRL/TMX/098/d/SVlts',[1425002881,]810,5440995,6143 7807 4076
'm/NWRL/TMX/098/d/status',[1425002885,]810,5489000,59897,-33.836465,151.051189
```