# How can I remove a carriage return, add a time stamp and ignore some data from a live MQTT feed

Tags: text-processing, streaming, data

I type `mosquitto_sub -d -t +/#` from the Ubuntu terminal to access the MQTT stream.

Real output from the live MQTT stream is this:

```
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/gf/TMX6BP/075/d/SVlts', ... (28 bytes))
86,1224830,27610 27869 17565
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/gf/TMX6BP/075/d/status', ... (39 bytes))
86,1243000,164573,-33.836465,151.051189
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/NWRL/TMX/098/d/SVlts', ... (26 bytes))
806,3040421,7549 7750 3904
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/NWRL/TMX/098/d/status', ... (39 bytes))
806,3069000,59666,-33.836465,151.051189
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/NWRL/TMX/098/d/SVlts', ... (26 bytes))
810,5440995,6143 7807 4076
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/NWRL/TMX/098/d/status', ... (39 bytes))
810,5489000,59897,-33.836465,151.051189
Sending PINGREQ
Received PINGRESP
```

There is no way of predicting when the next PUBLISH will be seen as they are only seen in the stream when the vehicle has transmission/reception from the GSM/3G towers

To filter I add `mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2> >(grep PUBLISH)` this will only allow lines with `PUBLISH` in it, hence the ouput is:

```
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/gf/TMX6BP/075/d/status', ... (38 bytes))
86,637999,164563,-33.836465,151.051189
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/NWRL/TMX/098/d/SVlts', ... (26 bytes))
806,3040421,7549 7750 3904
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/NWRL/TMX/098/d/status', ... (39 bytes))
806,3069000,59666,-33.836465,151.051189
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/gf/TMX6BP/075/d/SVlts', ... (28 bytes))
86,1224830,27610 27869 17565
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/gf/TMX6BP/075/d/status', ... (39 bytes))
86,1243000,164573,-33.836465,151.051189
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/NWRL/TMX/098/d/SVlts', ... (26 bytes))
806,3640483,7463 7721 3933
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/NWRL/TMX/098/d/status', ... (39 bytes))
806,3674000,59676,-33.836465,151.051189
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/NWRL/TMX/098/d/SVlts', ... (26 bytes))
806,4240543,7291 7750 3933
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/NWRL/TMX/098/d/status', ... (39 bytes))
806,4279000,59687,-33.836465,151.051189
Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/gf/MXE/065/d/SVlts', ... (25 bytes))
455,24715,28041 28041 967
```

How would I be able to eliminate a few of the fields and also add a time stamp everytime I receive something; I 've tried using `sed` but had no luck. I entered `$ mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2< <(grep PUBLISH) 2< <(sed "s/^/ date/")` , `` $ mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2< <(grep PUBLISH) 2< <(sed "s/^/$date`/") ``

**Q:** How can I change my input to the terminal so that the output from the above live feed would be:

```
[timestamp],m,gf,TMX6BP,075,d,status,86,637999,164563,-33.836465,151.051189
[timestamp],m,NWRL,TMX,098,d,SVlts,806,3040421,7549 7750 3904
[timestamp],m,NWRL,TMX,098,d,status,806,3069000,59666,-33.836465,151.051189
[timestamp],m,gf,TMX6BP,075,d,SVlts,86,1224830,27610 27869 17565
[timestamp],m,gf,TMX6BP,075,d,status,86,1243000,164573,-33.836465,151.051189
[timestamp],m,NWRL,TMX,098,d,SVlts,806,3640483,7463 7721 3933
[timestamp],m,NWRL,TMX,098,d,status,806,3674000,59676,-33.836465,151.051189
[timestamp],m,NWRL,TMX,098,d,SVlts,806,4240543,7291 7750 3933
[timestamp],m,NWRL,TMX,098,d,status,806,4279000,59687,-33.836465,151.051189
[timestamp],m,gf,MXE,065,d,SVlts,455,24715,28041 28041 967
```

Possible solutions (future referencing):

Using the `mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2> >(sed -n "s|.*\('.*',\).*|\1|p") | sed "N;s/\n/ /;s/$/ $(date)/"` The output is:

```
0 810,5440995,6143 7807 4076 Wed Feb 25 23:23:51 UTC 2015 810,5489000,59897,-33.836465,151.051189 810,6041055,7606 7693 4076 Wed Feb 25 23:23:51 UTC 2015
```

Using the `mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2> >(grep PUBLISH) | sed "N;s/\n/ /;s/$/ $(date)/"` command from the terminal the output is

```
817,3069000,60045,-33.836465,151.051189 609,24570,27553 27553 955 Thu Feb 26 00:06:26 UTC 2015
```

Using the `mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2>&1 | sed -n "/PUBLISH/{s|.*\('.*',\).*|\1|;N;s/\n/ /;s/$/ $(date)/;p}"` The output is

```
'm/gf/MX3/122/d/status', 610,33000,28162,-33.836465,151.051189 Thu Feb 26 01:18:17 UTC 2015
```

Comment: Why is the terminal input relevant? Do you mean, what command should you type or is there reason a filter should read from the terminal itself to get this information rather than `mosquito`'s stdout? Also, why do you think is the `86,6666......` appended line following a `PUBLISH` line in the second code block but not in the first one? Is a line like that not *always* going to follow a `PUBLISH` line?

Comment: @don_crissti -wilco; ALAS! `mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2>&1 | sed -n "/PUBLISH/{s|.*\('.*',\).*|\1|;N;s/\n/ /;s/$/ $(date)/;p}"` [has worked](http://oi57.tinypic.com/t6xo2g.jpg) I just need to understand what does what now :/ and why the others didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, rather confusing but anyway... Judging by the output of
`mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2> >(grep PUBLISH)`
your app seems to output to both `stderr` and `stdout` (otherwise you should only get lines matching `PUBLISH` in your output). It prints the debug messages (`Sending...` and `Received...`) to `stderr` and the actual data (`810,5440995,6143...`) to `stdout`.

---

Apparently, you need comma separated values so you could try the following, if you need the timestamp from the line matching `PUBLISH`:

```
mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2>&1 | xargs -d$'\n' -L1 sh -c 'date "+%s,$0"' | \
sed -n "/PUBLISH/{N;s|[ /]|,|g;s|^\([^,]*,\)[^']*'\([^']*\)',.*\n[^,]*,\(.*\)|\1\2,\3|;p}"
```

or, if you need the timestamp from the next line:

```
mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2>&1 | xargs -d$'\n' -L1 sh -c 'date "+%s,$0"' | \
sed -n "/PUBLISH/{N;s|[ /]|,|g;s|^[^,]*,[^']*'\([^']*\)',.*\n\([^,]*,\)\(.*\)|\2\1,\3|;p}"
```

---

`2>&1` redirects `stderr` to `stdout`, the output is then piped to `xargs` which passes each line as an argument to the next command `sh -c 'date "+%s,$0"'` so each line is prepended with a timestamp+comma, e.g.:

```
[timestamp],Sending PINGREQ
[timestamp],Received PINGRESP
[timestamp],Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'm/NWRL/TMX/098/d/status', ... (39 bytes))
[timestamp],871,40114,4536 4536 323
```

This is then piped to `sed` suppressing the automatic printing (`-n`).
For each line matching `PUBLISH`, append the `N`ext line, replace each space and `/` with comma then via grouping, retain only the first or second timestamp, the values in between quotes and the values after the second timestamp and finally, print the result:

```
[timestamp],m,NWRL,TMX,098,d,status,871,40114,4536,4536,323
```

Comment: I've [looked into xargs](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/12/xargs-examples/) I am understanding it a bit. How can I shift the the time stamp between before `\1\2`? ie `[timestamp],m/NWRL/TMX/098/d/SVlts, 806,3040421,7549 7750 3904`

Comment: it works :( but it endlines [the output here](http://www.codeshare.io/M0KyM)

Comment: you've got every right to be angry. but the guy responsible of me, is currently overseas, and we can't really communicate, so everything is a 2-3 days delayed. I will abide by you, and make it into a CSV file, I will look into it when I go home... don_cristi, thank you for your help thus far.. :)

Comment: there is one thing I want to do, and I will try to do it.. and if I can't, I promise you that will be the last question I will ask... but I think thank you is an understatement for the help and guidance you've given me. thank you!

Comment: white flags up, the terminal has defeated me! [My last question](http://www.codeshare.io/M0KyM) is if you assist me with a minor tweek. And I will disappear! Many thanks!

Comment: it works! thank you! oh man, you rock my world! My first borns name: don_crissti, a tribute to you :)

Comment: I've looked at your code last night, and played around with it for a bit. I removed the `$` from `xargs -d$'\n' -L1 sh -c 'date....` so that its `xargs -d'\n' -L1 sh -c 'date...` and also I've removed the ` \ ` before the `sed`... it works great. What is the purpose of this two symbols?

Comment: I've embedded that line of code into a bash script. I am currently trying to figure out how to make it execute on startup/booting of the system. I figured via crontab I can type in `@root /some directory to my script/script.txt` and should work, and there is also the `init.d` way which I am currently looking into.

Comment: Very nice answer.  Any simple way to pipe that output to a file?

Comment: @don_crissti thanks for the quick reply!  I tried your suggestion first and for whatever reason it doesn't actually write the file.  If I just run the command by itself it works.  I have write access and a simple ```echo 'test' > myfile``` works.  I thought perhaps it was different with how xargs works or something (I never understood the magic voodoo that is xargs).

Comment: I also put the command in a script and ran it with the ```> myfile``` to no avail.

Comment: @don_crissti Yes, I'm adding it right to the end of the command.  [Here's a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/MsOlsar.png).  I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 and bash.  The MQTT stream is at 1 Hz and I verify that it prints to the screen at that rate.  It's weird to me, seems like it should work.

Comment: @don_crissti Interesting.  I started it again and did a tail and didn't see anything so I let it run while I moved on to something else.  Seems after about ten minutes it actually wrote the file and the tail spit out all of that data.  The data is at roughly 1 Hz as expected.  Any thoughts?  Is there some kind of flush I could do on the file to force it to write every time?

Comment: @ChuckClaunch - well, yeah, as I suspected, this is because of the pipe buffering - not much you can do other than use `sed` with  `-u` (if you're using `gnu sed` that is) to force it unbuffer but that's all...

Comment: @don_crissti That works perfect!  I just added that ```-u``` to the ```sed``` call and it works perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: @ChuckClaunch - no problem buddy, anytime !

Answer (score 0):

I simulated mosquitto in bash/ksh environment and found

```
stub_mosquitto | 
   sed -e 's/.*m0, //' -e 's/, .*bytes))//' | while read line; do
      if [[ "${line}" = \'* ]]; then
         echo -n "${line}, "
      else
         echo "${line}, $(date)"
      fi
   done
```

I used sed here for cutting the interesting parts.
I use while read line for a simple way of joining 2 lines (and adding a date). This is possible with sed or tr, but that might need some work to (different versions of sed).

I do not understand the call to mosquitto_sub exactly, so I only show the solution when the strings come through a pipe:

- What is the `#` doing there?
  Without quotes it should be the start of the comment
- How do you get a line with numbers when you grep for a string?
  Are the numbers written to stderr? After redirecting them to stdout with `2>&1` grep will skip them.

Comment: would you be able to elaborate where and how I could implement this? (Apologies - totally new to Unix/programming)

Comment: Walter - why would you `sed | read`?

Comment: @mikeserv See updated answer with some explanation.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense - do the join with `sed` - with `read` you only floor your efficiency and possibly mangle your input.

Comment: @mikeserv You are right. Joining lines with sed is much more efficient. I could have found the special syntax for removing `\n` on SO, I just tried to show a general approach in a "simple" way.