# How can I pipe only stderr in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh, pipe, io-redirection, stderr

In bash:

```
$ echo hi 2>&1 1>/dev/null | cat
$
```

While in zsh:

```
$ echo hi 2>&1 1>/dev/null | cat
hi
$
```

Is there a way to pipe only standard error while redirecting standard out?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With zsh and with the [`mult_ios` option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios) on (on by default), in:

```
echo hi 2>&1 1>/dev/null | cat
```

The `1> /dev/null | cat` is seen as a multiple redirection of `echo`'s stdout.

So `echo`'s stdout is now redirected to both `/dev/null` and a pipe to `cat` (as if using `tee`).

To cancel that multiple redirection, you can do:

```
echo hi 2>&1 >&- > /dev/null | cat
```

That is, closing stdout (cancelling the piping) before redirecting to `/dev/null`

Or use a command group or subshell like:

```
{echo hi 2>&1 1>/dev/null} | cat 
(echo hi 2>&1 1>/dev/null) | cat
```

That way, `echo`'s stdout is only redirected explicitly *once* (the pipe redirection is applied to the group/subshell and inherited by `echo`).

Or you can disable `multios` altogether:

```
(set +o multios; echo hi 2>&1 > /dev/null | cat)
```

Alternatively, you could use *process substitution* instead of a pipe:

```
echo hi 2> >(cat) > /dev/null
```

Beware however that when job control is off (like in scripts), the `cat` process will be running asynchronously (as if started with `&`).

Comment: Thanks!  Another way to get around it is `(echo hi 2>&1 1>/dev/null) | cat`.

Comment: @TavianBarnes, good point, thanks. I've added it to the answer for completeness. It also works with a command group (`{echo...}|cat`)