# Possible redirection bug in zsh 5x

Tags: zsh, io-redirection

The following command produces different outputs in zsh v. 4.x and 5.x:

```
{
  (
    printf "X\nY\n"
    printf "WARNING: foo\nWARNING: bar\n" >&2
    printf "1\n2\n"
  ) 2>&1 >&3 | grep -v foo >&2
} 3>&1
```

(This code is supposed to illustrate how to selectively suppress some of the output sent to stderr by a program; in this case, the warning `foo` is being suppressed selectively, while the warning `bar` is allowed to go through; note that in the end, `stderr` and `stdout` streams remain separate.)

On v 4.x the output I see at the terminal is as desired/expected:

```
X
Y
1
2
WARNING: bar
```

(You may see a different ordering of the `WARNING: bar` line relative to the other ones.)

On v 5.0.7 (Debian) and 5.1.1 (Darwin), however, what I see at the terminal is this:

```
X
Y
1
2
WARNING: bar
X
Y
1
2
```

IOW, the lines that should be sent to `stdout` appear twice.

I figure there are three possibilities:

1. this is a bug in v. 5.x (in which case my question is: is there a workaround?)
2. I have not properly configured my v. 5.x zsh (in which case my question is: how should I configure my v. 5.x zsh to get the desired behavior?);
3. there is a bug in v. 4.x, but not in v. 5.x, that masked a bug in my code (in which case my question is: how could I fix my code to get the desired behavior in v 5.x?)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that both `dash` and `bash` produce the same behaviour as `zsh` 4, which lends credence to the hypothesis that the original behaviour was correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the bug was in 4.0 and has been fixed.

What you're seeing is the effect of the `multios` options, specific to `zsh`. If you want to see the same behaviour as in other shells, you need to disable that option `setopt nomultios` or call `zsh` as `sh`.

With `multios`, in `cmd1 >&3 | cmd2`, you're redirecting `cmd1`'s stdout to both `&3` and the pipe to `cmd2`. See [How can I pipe only stderr in zsh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/265061) for more details.

Comment: I was very curious about this question myself and I knew I could count on you coming along with the answer :-)