# Filtering standard error output from remote BorgBackup repository

Tags: remote, filter, borgbackup

I want to filter standard error for a command that prints status information to standard error. In this case, [Borg Backup](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Specifically, the default output of `borg check` includes lines like:

```
Checking segments ...
```

sent to standard error. I want to filter those lines out, because they are a nuisance for a cron job. Currently (as of `1.0.2`) it is not possible to disable this output via `borg` configuration.

I used [the approach described by Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3540/4671). This works fine for a local Borg repository, for example:

```
{ borg check '/media/faheem/My Passport/backup-Mail' 2>&1 1>&3 | tr '\r' '\n' | grep -v "^Checking segments" 1>&2; } 3>&1
```

However, the situation is a little different for a remote repository. The output looks like

```
Remote: Checking segments 99.3% 
Remote:
```

How would one modify the reverse grep to get rid of both of these cases?

```
{ borg check faheem@ramnode:/mnt/backup-Mail 2>&1 1>&3 | tr '\r' '\n' | grep -v ":Checking segments" 1>&2; } 3>&1
```

works for the first case, but not the second, namely just `Remote:`. I could use two greps, but I'd prefer one expression.

Answer (score 1):

To filter out either message in one grep, pull in the `-E` extended regular expression flag (for the "zero or once" meaning of `?` below), and the `-v` inverse match:

```
grep -Ev '^Remote:( Checking segments [[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]%)?$'
```

which says that the lines should (inverse) match:

- beginning of line `^`
- the string `Remote:`
- the grouped `(` ... `)` set of characters (with a leading space) `Checking segments ...`, matched either zero or one times with: `?`
- the `[[:digit:]]` section says to match between 1 and 3 digit, followed by a period, followed by one digit, and then the `%` symbol
- all anchored to the end of the line `$`

Upon further clarification from the OP, the final grep looks like:

```
grep -Ev "^Remote:\s*(Checking segments.*)?$"
```

Which removes any line matching (starting at the beginning `^` of the line), the word "Remote:", then any (or no) amount of whitespace, then either:

- nothing, or
- the phrase "Checking segments" itself followed by any (or no) characters `.*`

... and then the end of the line `$`

Comment: Hi Jeff, this gets blocked, which I don't want: `echo "Remote: xx" | grep -Ev '^Remote:( Checking segments)?'`. And what is the `E` flag required for?

Comment: I extended the RE so that the two things it's looking for must match the entire line (anchored in '$'), and so I also had to fill in the percentage RE.

Comment: It should suffice to just match `Checking segments`, and allow anything after it. Plus that would be simpler.

Comment: Replace all that digit stuff with .* then, leaving the $ at the end to anchor

Comment: So, what would that look like then? `grep -Ev '^Remote:( Checking segments :.*)?$'`?

Comment: That looks basically correct. Your original didn't have a colon after segments, so use whatever is right :)

Comment: Hi Jeff, I wound up using `{ borg check faheem@ramnode:/mnt/backup-Mail 2>&1 1>&3 | tr '\r' '\n' | grep -Ev "^Remote:\s*(Checking segments.*)?$" 1>&2; } 3>&1`. If you can either change your answer to that, or append it to the answer, I'll accept it. I wasn't clear on the point of the last `$`, so I left it out.

Comment: appended. I see you kept the '$' in your latest comment; that anchors to the end of the line, so that you *don't* omit lines like "Remote: xx" (as per your [earlier](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280130/filtering-standard-error-output-from-remote-borgbackup-repository/280291?noredirect=1#comment487479_280291) comment)