# How to grep XRDP version number?

Tags: grep, version, xrdp

Not able to grep xrdp version line by running below command on ubuntu 14.04

```
$ sudo xrdp -v | grep -i "version"
```

Output : Blank

```
$ sudo xrdp -v
```

Output :

```
logging configuration:
    LogFile:       /var/log/xrdp.log
    LogLevel:      4
    EnableSyslog:  1
    SyslogLevel:   4

xrdp: A Remote Desktop Protocol server.
Copyright (C) Jay Sorg 2004-2014
See http://www.xrdp.org for more information.
Version 0.9.0
```

Where as when try with  other program like below `perl command`

```
$ sudo perl -V | grep "version"
```

Output :

```
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 18 subversion 2) configuration:
```

How to get version 0.9.0 as output of command !

Comment: may be the xrdp output is to stderr? if so, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/how-to-grep-standard-error-stream-stderr might help

Comment: tried `$ sudo xrdp -V  2>&1 | grep Version` but still blank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xrdp` writes to 1, that is `stdout` as shown by `strace` but it looks that it buffers its output for some reasons. Try this:

```
$ unbuffer xrdp -v | grep Version
Version 0.9.4
```

Alternatively you can use `stdbuf`:

```
$ stdbuf  -o0  xrdp -v | grep Version
Version 0.9.4
```

Comment: Ok this works, but for that i have to install `unbuffer` program & its packages. Installing on 40 to 50 servers machine would make it difficult. Any other way !!!

Comment: You might have more luck with `stdbuf`, it's a part of `GNU coreutils`.

Comment: Interestingly, I found the root cause of this behavior.  In
`common/os_calls.c` they use `_exit()` instead of `exit()` and as `man
_exit` says: `Open stdio(3) streams are not flushed.  On the other
hand, _exit() does close open file descriptors, and this may cause an
unknown delay, waiting for pending output to finish.  If the delay is
undesired, it may be useful to call functions like tcflush(3) before
calling _exit().  Whether any pending I/O is canceled, and which
pending I/O may be canceled upon _exit(), is
implementation-dependent.`.

Comment: Changing `_exit()` to `exit()` makes it
possible to grep `-v` output without `unbuffer`.