# Swapping STD{OUT,ERR} in a pipeline multiple times

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/341014/143394), I wrote the following which swaps file descriptors 1 and 2:

`swap12`:

```
#!/bin/bash
"$@" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-
```

I can then operate on STDERR in a pipeline, eg:

```
$ swap12 ls -ld /tmp /ooooooo | tr o X
ls: cannXt access '/XXXXXXX': NX such file Xr directXry
drwxrwxrwt 19 root root 1400 Jul  1 17:14 /tmp
```

However swapping the FDs doesn't work multiple times:

```
$ swap12 ls -ld /tmp /ooooooo | swap12 tr o X | tr o Z
ls: cannXt access '/XXXXXXX': NX such file Xr directXry
drwxrwxrwt 19 root root 1400 Jul  1 17:14 /tmp
```

Above I'm expecting the 2nd `swap12` to again swap STDOUT and STDRR, so the 2nd `tr` would operate on `ls`'s original STDOUT. I'm expecting to see:

```
$ swap12 ls -ld /tmp /ooooooo | swap12 tr o X | tr o Z
ls: cannXt access '/XXXXXXX': NX such file Xr directXry
drwxrwxrwt 19 rZZt rZZt 1400 Jul  1 17:14 /tmp
```

How can I achieve what I'm after?

I have the feeling that my problem is due to changing the file descriptors in subshells. Would there be an advantage to implementation as `zsh` global `alias -g` alias? (But then how would the `bash` implementation look?)

Comment: Can you add to the question, to show the output that you were expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, `stderr` goes directly to the terminal, and `stdout` goes to the pipe:

```
          ls stdout -->
ls -ld /tmp /ooooooo | tr o X
 |
 v ls stderr (to terminal)
```

After you swap them, `stdout` goes to the terminal, and not to the pipe:

```
                 ls stderr -->
swap12 ls -ld /tmp /ooooooo | tr o X
        |
        v ls stdout
```

Swapping `stdout`/`stderr` of the `tr` doesn't involve the resulting `stderr` of `ls` in any way, as it was redirected away from the pipeline earlier.

```
                 ls stderr -->   tr stderr -->
swap12 ls -ld /tmp /ooooooo | swap12 tr o X | tr o Z
        |                             |
        v ls stdout                   v tr stdout
```

If you want to process the `stdout` and `stderr` of `ls` separately, you could use process substitution (should work in Bash and Zsh):

```
$ ls -ld /tmp /ooooooo 2> >(tr o X)  > >(tr o Z) 
ls: cannXt access '/XXXXXXX': NX such file Xr directXry
drwxrwxrwt 25 rZZt rZZt 4096 Jul  1 14:40 /tmp/
```

Answer (score 0):

The pipe has connected `ls.stderr` to `tr1.stdin`. You then swap `tr1.stdout` and `tr1.stderr` and pipe `tr1.stderr` to `tr2.stdin` tr2 finds no `o`s so does nothing.

The 2nd `swap12` should not and does not undo the first.

Were you intending to do `./swap12 ./swap12 ls -ld /tmp /ooooooo |  tr o X`. This undos the swapping.