# Is it possible to grep this output from gpg

Tags: grep, gpg

Take the following command (real example) :

```
~$ gpg --edit-key foo@bar.net showpref quit
(...)
[ultimate] (1). Foo Bar <foo@bar.net>
     Cipher: AES256, AES192, AES, CAST5, 3DES
     AEAD: 
     Digest: SHA256, SHA1, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
     Compression: ZLIB, BZIP2, ZIP, Uncompressed
     Features: MDC, AEAD, Keyserver no-modify
     Preferred keyserver: ldap://keyserver.pgp.com
~$
```

Piping the output into a `| grep` doesn't work :

```
~$ gpg --edit-key foo@bar.net showpref quit | grep Compression
(...)
[ultimate] (1). Foo Bar <foo@bar.net>
     Cipher: AES256, AES192, AES, CAST5, 3DES
     AEAD: 
     Digest: SHA256, SHA1, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
     Compression: ZLIB, BZIP2, ZIP, Uncompressed
     Features: MDC, AEAD, Keyserver no-modify
     Preferred keyserver: ldap://keyserver.pgp.com
~$
```

Is there a way to make that work ? E.g., the result I'd like to get is :

```
~$ gpg --edit-key foo@bar.net showpref quit | grep Compression
     Compression: ZLIB, BZIP2, ZIP, Uncompressed
~$
```

[EDIT : what I tried so far ] :

@steeldriver, @RomeoNinov : I don't think redirecting `stderr` is going to do the trick. It doesn't look like `gpg`'s output goes to `stderr`.

Basically, `gpg` is an interactive command, but launching `gpg ... cmd1 cmd2` makes it non-interactive (e.g., `gpg ... showpref quit` is the same as doing interactively `showpref` followed by `quit` in `gpg`'s shell).

@steeldriver :

```
~$ gpg --edit-key foo@bar.net showpref quit 2> >(grep Compression)
(...)
[ultimate] (1). Foo Bar <foo@bar.net>
     Cipher: AES256, AES192, AES, CAST5, 3DES
     AEAD: 
     Digest: SHA256, SHA1, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
     Compression: ZLIB, BZIP2, ZIP, Uncompressed
     Features: MDC, AEAD, Keyserver no-modify
     Preferred keyserver: ldap://keyserver.pgp.com
~$
```

@RomeoNinov :

```
~$ gpg --edit-key foo@bar.net showpref quit 2>&1| grep Compression
(...)
[ultimate] (1). Foo Bar <foo@bar.net>
     Cipher: AES256, AES192, AES, CAST5, 3DES
     AEAD: 
     Digest: SHA256, SHA1, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
     Compression: ZLIB, BZIP2, ZIP, Uncompressed
     Features: MDC, AEAD, Keyserver no-modify
     Preferred keyserver: ldap://keyserver.pgp.com
~$
```

Comment: Are you sure the issue here is a subshell - rather than [How to grep standard error stream (stderr)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/how-to-grep-standard-error-stream-stderr)

Comment: Have you try: `gpg --edit-key foo@bar.net showpref quit 2>&1| grep Compression`?

Comment: @steeldriver : I've seen that page before, and tried it, but it didn't work (see my edit). It doesn't look like `gpg`'s output goes to stderr.

Comment: @RomeoNinov : yes, see my EDIT. Same result, not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use `--batch`. This will help `gpg` to send info to standard file handlers.

```
# gpg  --batch --edit-key user@example.net showpref quit 2>&1 |grep Com
     Compression: ZLIB, BZIP2, ZIP, Uncompressed
```

Comment: When called without `--batch`, where does `gpg --edit-key foo@bar.net showpref quit` send it's output if not `stdout` or `stderr`?

Comment: @EdMorton, did not check how it do this but it send to the "current" console/terminal, avoiding STDOUT and STDERR. Why? Have no idea :)